# Finding a repository LOC's added in a specific commit

Tags: mercurial, lines-of-code

Is it possible to find a repository's total lines of code added in a specific commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The churn extension does what I need:

```
hg churn --rev 100
```

Answer (score 2):

See also the `--stat` flag to `hg log` in newer versions of Mercurial. That gives you "diffstat" output:

```
% hg log -l 3 --stat
changeset:   304:eb7e19e5021c
tag:         tip
user:        Martin Geisler 
date:        Wed Mar 30 12:26:41 2011 +0200
summary:     po-da: translated about

 po/da.po |  26 ++++++++++++++++++++++----
 1 files changed, 22 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)

changeset:   303:0104b63e904b
user:        Martin Geisler 
date:        Wed Mar 30 00:03:47 2011 +0200
summary:     po-cs: remove unknown (illegal) escape sequence

 po/cs.po |  4 ++--
 1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

changeset:   302:3b23518c9723
user:        Martin Geisler 
date:        Wed Mar 30 00:03:23 2011 +0200
summary:     po-cs: remove extra newline

 po/cs.po |  2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```